# How to build 2-layer fuzzy inference system

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

I am implementing a fuzzy logic based decision support system that uses nine variables but group each three together to form an output then take these three output to make the final output of the system.

I am using fuzzy logic toolbox in matlab, I made each one of these three outputs but I can't figure out how I can make these outputs as inputs again for the final output.

The system is shown in this picture:

[system picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1vka.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you would need two FIS separately , where the inputs from the second one will be the outputs from the first one.

Sorry If I didn't help much :/

Comment: I was searching before if matlab supports these kinds of multi-layer fuzzy inference systems but as I found it only supports the simple one layer systems

Comment: I hope I helped! I'm also using the matlab toolbox for a mamdani FIS and yeah, I think there's an option for multi-layer. Thank you :)